# Some problems to inconify a JFrame window when the user click on the X button in this specific case, some ideas?

Tags: java, swing, events, jframe, actionlistener

I have the following problem: I am working on a Java Swing application that show me a JFrame. What I have to do is that when the user click on the X button the window have to be iconified and not close (it is a requirement requested by the client)

My architecture is pretty complicated and it work in this way:

I have a class named **GUI** that is something like this:

```
public class GUI extends SingleFrameApplication implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private MainFrame mainFrame = null;

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
        showMainFrame();
        }

    private void showMainFrame() {

        mainFrame = new MainFrame(settings, tasksSettings, logAppender);
        // I add a PropertyChangeListener to the created MainFrame object:
        mainFrame.addPropertyChangeListener(this);

        //mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                logger.info("Minimize the MainFrameWindows instead close it");
                ((MainFrame)e.getSource()).setState(MainFrame.ICONIFIED);
                logger.info("EVENTO ICONIZZAZIONE: " + e.getSource().toString());
            }
        });

        WindowListener exitListener = new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println("GUI SingleFrameApplication --> windowClosing");
                mainFrame.OnWindowClose();
                shutdown();
                // mainFrame.setVisible(false);
                /*int confirm = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(frame,
                "Are You Sure to Close this Application?",
                "Exit Confirmation", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, null, null);
                if (confirm == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(1);
                }*/
            }
        };

        mainFrame.addWindowListener(exitListener);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
@Override
protected void shutdown() {
    System.out.println("Entered into GUI ---> shutdown()");
    logger.debug("Termino l'applicazione.");
    ulogger.info(com.techub.crystalice.utils.Constants.APP_TITLE + "|Arresto " + com.techub.crystalice.utils.Constants.APP_TITLE);
    // FileUtils.saveGeneralLogFile(logAppender.getLogInFile());
    logAppender.saveGeneralLogFile();
    EventBusService.unsubscribe(this);
    if (mainFrame != null)
        mainFrame.setVisible(false);

}

}
```

So in the previous code I have declared the **showMainFrame()** method and in this method I add a window listener that have to iconize my MainFrame JFrame, in this way

```
        mainFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                logger.info("Minimize the MainFrameWindows instead close it");
                ((MainFrame)e.getSource()).setState(MainFrame.ICONIFIED);
                logger.info("EVENTO ICONIZZAZIONE: " + e.getSource().toString());
            }
        });
```

Then I have my **MainFrame** windows that extends a classic **JFrame**, something like this:

public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

```
private final ConfigHelper settings;
private final TasksSettings tasksSettings;

public MainFrame(ConfigHelper settings, TasksSettings tasksSettings, LogAppender logAppender) {
    super();

    this.settings = settings;
    this.tasksSettings = tasksSettings;

            .......................................................
            .......................................................
            .......................................................
            DO SOME STUFF
            .......................................................
            .......................................................
            .......................................................
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

}
```

The problem is that when I click on the X button of my **MainFrane** window it will be close and not iconified.

Can you help me to solve this situation and in such a way that the MainFrame window is iconified and not closed?

I think that the problem is that at the end of execution it execute the **shutDown()** method that execute this operation:

```
if (mainFrame != null)
mainFrame.setVisible(false);
```

so the windows is not iconified but closed\made it invisible

Some idea?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly, you need to show an icon for the app in system tray when you hit the X button, is it true?

In this case, you have enough with the default behavior for close event (the default is hide on close, as stated in documentation).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

In order to manage a system tray icon, you have some hints here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html

In the system tray, you would have the necessary code to hide or show the main window (I don't know, but maybe you don't even need a window listener at all in your JFrame)